# SQL join to duplicate rows which meet certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view, reporting-services

I have a view which pulls back 46,712 records which include the following 2 fields:

**StartDate** &
**EndDate**

I need to add a new column to be called 'Period', in this column I need to have each record listed as either **'Cumulative'** or **'Non Cumulative'**

The problem with this is that firstly all of my records need to have a **'Cumulative'** row, and every record that is active in the current month must also have a **'Non-Cumulative'** row.

The rules that apply for a record to qualify to be classed as **Non-Cumulative** are the following:

**EndDate = NULL**

**EndDate within the current month**

As all my rows no matter what the criteria must have a 'Cumulative' row, I must therfore duplicate any rows which qualify for the 'Non-Cumulative' type using some sort of JOIN.

So if i have 46712 rows and 200 of these are **'Non-Cumulative'** I should end up with 46,812 rows. (200 being duplicate apart from the Cumulative/Non Cumulative result.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I should go about doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question then this should do what you need.

```
Declare @rowType as table (rowTypeLabel nvarchar(20))
Insert Into @rowType 
Values ('Cumulative')
Insert Into @rowType 
Values ('Non-Cumulative')

Select StartDate, EndDate, rowTypeLabel As Period
From dbo.YourTable
        Cross Join @rowType
Where (@rowType = 'Cumulative'
        Or (@rowType = 'Non-Cumulative' And ( EndDate is null
                    Or 
                 EndDate Between 
                            Cast(DateAdd(Day, 1 - Day(getDate()), getdate()) as date)
                            And
                            Cast(DateAdd(month, 1, DateAdd(Day,  - Day(getDate()), getdate())) as date))
                )
```

Comment: have added this into my main query however it has increased my run time from around 10 minutes to around 50 minutes, Is this because of the cross join? Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same result?

Comment: I'd take a look at the query plan. Given the number of rows in the cross joined table, the above would only increase the number of potential rows processed by a factor of 2, I'd be more likely to suspect that the problem would be related to getdate() in the were clause meaning that no indexes are being used. If this is the case you could precalculate the values of start of month and end of month before the query and pass them in. Since the where clause would then be deterministic the indexes should be used.